# React, is there a way to avoid needing to wrap a div inside a div?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have the following:

```
const errorMessage = ({meta}) =>
  <div>
    {meta.error && meta.touched && <div className="alert alert-info" role="alert">{meta.error}</div>}
  </div>
```

If I remove the outer div wrapper in the above I get an error... Is there a way to get errorMessage to work without the extra DIV?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid extra wrapping <div> in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33766085/how-to-avoid-extra-wrapping-div-in-react)

Comment: Thanks all, I realize React required the div wrapping, I'm wondering if there is some magic JS that would allow the above to be rewritten to not require that extra div, if that makes sense?

Comment: You can make a function that wraps it in a div for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write it like this by using `{}`:

```
const ErrorMessage = ({meta}) => {

    if(meta.error && meta.touched)
        return <div className="alert alert-info" role="alert">{meta.error}</div>

    return null;
}
```

Or remove the outer `div` and remove the `{}` also, use `ternary operator` to put the condition, like this:

```
const ErrorMessage = ({meta}) => meta.error && meta.touched ? 
    <div className="alert alert-info" role="alert">{meta.error}</div>
    : null;
```

You need to use `ErrorMessage` instead of `errorMessage`, check the reason here:

[Html is not rendering in the browser - React js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42110144/html-is-not-rendering-in-the-browser-react-js)

Check **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44849764/5185595)** why it was failing when you removed the outer `div`:

```
const errorMessage = ({meta}) => 
    {meta.error && meta.touched && <div className="alert alert-info" role="alert">{meta.error}</div>}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write like this :

```
const errorMessage = ({meta}) => {
return (meta.error && meta.touched) ? `<div className='alert alert-info' role='alert'>${meta.error}</div>` : null
}
```