# Save with firebase with a dynamic key name

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, vue.js

I am trying to insert in my database the month chosen by the user.

```
saveInBdd (){
  this.errors = [];

  const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
  user.updateProfile({
    displayName: this.firstname,
  }).then(()=>{
    this.saveUserToUsersRef(user)
  }, error => {
    this.errors.push(error.message)
  })
},
saveUserToUsersRef(user){
  return this.usersRef.child(user.uid).update({
    tab1: { this.months[0].selectedOption : "test"}
  })
},
```

This code returns this error to me:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React.js - Syntax error: this is a reserved word in render() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44849206/react-js-syntax-error-this-is-a-reserved-word-in-render-function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property name of a JSON object in the notation you're using needs to be a literal. To use a variable as the name of a property, use `[]` notation:

```
saveUserToUsersRef(user){
  var updates = {};
  updates[this.months[0].selectedOption] = "test";
  return this.usersRef.child(user.uid).update(updates))
},
```

Comment: If I want to add a JSON to updates how can I do without deleted what is in?

2018 : {
  january : {
    data : xx
  },
  february : {
    data : xx
  },
}

Comment: If you want to update a specific value, make sure you use the path to that value in the key of the updates. E.g. `updates['2018/january/data'] = 'xx'`.

Comment: In fact I want to put database data according to a year and a month given by the user. I tested: year[this.years[0].selectedOption/year[this.months[0].selectedOption/data] = "xx" but it did not work

Comment: Seems like that should be `year[this.years[0].selectedOption/year[this.months[0].selectedOption+"/data"] = "xx"`

Comment: With your firebase code shows me : 2018 : { undefined : { data : xx } }