# this is a reserved word React Native

Tags: react-native, react-redux

I have been trying rendering this. But all the time the error this is a reserved word occurs. It says line 170 which equals the function {this.onRenderValidation(validation)} in the return statement. Any one know what I did wrong?
Thank you guys!

```
onRenderValidation(validation){


  <Card>

    <CardSection>
      <Input
        label="Email"
        placeholder="email@gmail.com"
        onChangeText={this.onEmailChange.bind(this)}
        value={this.props.email}
      />
    </CardSection>
    <Text>
    {this.renderValidationError(validation.email)}
    </Text>
    <CardSection>
      <Input
        secret={true}
        label="Passwort"
        placeholder="password"
        onChangeText={this.onPasswordChange.bind(this)}
        value={this.props.password}
      />
    </CardSection>
    <Text>
    {this.renderValidationError(validation.password)}
    </Text>
    //{this.renderError()}

    <CardSection>
      {this.renderButton()}
    </CardSection>
    <CardSection>
      {this.render2Button()}
    </CardSection>
  </Card>

}

render(){
let validation=this.submitted ? this.validator.validate(this.state) : 
this.state.validation;
return(

   {this.onRenderValidation(validation)}

)
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are returning an object, not a JSX element. Just change it to:

```
render(){
    let validation = this.submitted ? this.validator.validate(this.state) : this.state.validation;
    return this.onRenderValidation(validation);
}
```

Alternatively, wrap it in a JSX element:

```
render(){
    let validation = this.submitted ? this.validator.validate(this.state) : this.state.validation;
    return (
      <div>{this.onRenderValidation(validation)}</div>
    )
}
```

For more info on why this happens, check out a similar question here and the top answer: [React.js - Syntax error: this is a reserved word in render() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44849206/react-js-syntax-error-this-is-a-reserved-word-in-render-function)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It worked. Now another Error does occur: Nothing was returned from render. Do you know why?

Comment: You need to return the JSX element in your `onRenderValidation` function. So wrap everything in that function in a `return()`, like this: 

`onRenderValidation = (validation) => { return (<Card>...</Card>)}`

If you note, I also modified your function to use fat arrow syntax. That is so that your `this` in the `onRenderValidation` behaves how you would expect it.